# My emacs-jedi won't find a package

Tags: python, emacs-jedi

In my `.emacs` I have `(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/home/username/python-packages")` where I have some packages that I use and develop. Unfortunately, `emacs-jedi` won't find them, and it won't autocomplete them. How can I debug it and solve the problem?

For reference, here is my `jedi:show-setup-info`:

```lisp
;; Emacs Lisp version:
(:emacs-version "24.3.1" :jedi-version "0.2.0alpha2" :python-environment-version "0.0.2alpha0")
;; Python version:
((:version "2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) \n[GCC 4.6.3]" :name "sys" :file nil)
 (:version "0.8.1-final0" :name "jedi" :file "/home/username/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.5" :name "epc" :file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/epc/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.3" :name "sexpdata" :file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexpdata.pyc"))
;; Command line:
(:virtualenv "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv" :virtualenv-version "1.11.6\n")
;; Customization:
((jedi:complete-on-dot)
 (jedi:doc-display-buffer . display-buffer)
 (jedi:doc-hook view-mode)
 (jedi:doc-mode . rst-mode)
 (jedi:environment-root)
 (jedi:environment-virtualenv)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-delay . 1000)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-timeout . 3000)
 (jedi:goto-definition-config
  (nil nil nil)
  (t nil nil)
  (nil definition nil)
  (t definition nil)
  (nil nil t)
  (t nil t)
  (nil definition t)
  (t definition t))
 (jedi:goto-definition-marker-ring-length . 16)
 (jedi:imenu-create-index-function . jedi:create-nested-imenu-index)
 (jedi:import-python-el-settings . t)
 (jedi:install-imenu)
 (jedi:install-python-jedi-dev-command "pip" "install" "--upgrade" "git+https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git@dev#egg=jedi")
 (jedi:key-complete .
            [C-tab])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition .
               [67108910])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker .
                      [67108908])
 (jedi:key-related-names . "r")
 (jedi:key-show-doc . "d")
 (jedi:server-args)
 (jedi:server-command "/home/username/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver")
 (jedi:setup-keys)
 (jedi:tooltip-method pos-tip popup)
 (jedi:use-shortcuts)
 (python-environment-default-root-name . "default")
 (python-environment-directory . "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments")
 (python-environment-virtualenv "virtualenv" "--system-site-packages" "--quiet"))
```